# how to resolve "EWS could not contact the appropriate CAS server for this request"

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have an application that is creating StreamingSubscription (using EWS managed API) for many hundreds of room resource mailboxes in EXO, and I'm trying to make the code tolerant of a subscription going "bad" and needing to be re-created.  Here's the behavior I'm seeing at the moment.

I first divide up the mailboxes into groups according to best practices, and then within each group:

1. I create a StreamingSubscription for each mailbox
2. I add all the subscriptions to a connection and open the connection
3. Some time passes, and the OnSubscriptionError event fires for
   one subscription.  At this point I find that the subscription in
   question is no longer in the connection's CurrentSubscriptions
   collection, but I'm able to identify which mailbox it was originally
   for.
4. I then flag that mailbox so that the code will try to re-create its
   subscription.
5. When the code tries to re-create the failed subscription, this error is thrown:

```
Request failed because EWS could not contact the appropriate CAS server for this request.
```

Thereafter, my code tries again once per minute to create that subscription, and that same error is thrown each time.  This continues for as long as I allow it to run.

If I then stop my Windows service and start it again, all the subscriptions are created successfully, including that failed one.

Here's my question.  Why is it able to successfully create the subscription after stopping and re-starting the service, but can't re-create it after the OnSubscriptionError?

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue because of the retry period what happens if you increase the wait time before retrying ?.  You could also try https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/error-improvement-for-invalid-x-anchormailbox-in-rest-api-calls/ (although I've not tried this in EWS but I know thing like Outlook Mobile actually use the PUID instead in the Anchor-Mailbox header instead of the SMTP Address)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, we'll try setting the anchor mailbox header to the mailbox GUID instead of SMTP address and report back.